# JQuery $.post error

Tags: php, jquery, .post

I'm desktop developer and new with web dev. My function is returning an error, above the function:

```
function briefingScreen(gameObjectElement)
{
    $(gameObjectElement).html('<div id="briefing"></div>');
    $("#briefing").append('<div id="start_button"></div>');
    $("#briefing").append('<div id="briefing_text"></div>');
    $.post("php/text.php", "teste",//{screen: "briefingScreen", field:"mainText"},
        function(callback)
        {
            $.("#briefing_text").html(callback);
        }, "html");

        $("#start_button").click(function()
        {
            window.alert("Start Button");
        }
    }
```

I'm debugging in google chrome and the error is `Uncaught  SyntaxError: Unexpected Token )`.

I already searched but didn't found a solution. Anyone can help?

Comment: For one thing, `$.("#briefing_text").html(callback);` should not have a period - should be `$('#briefing_Text').html(callback);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the //comment from:

`$.post("php/text.php", "teste",//{screen: "briefingScreen", field:"mainText"},`

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly close your click function:

```
$("#start_button").click(function() {
    window.alert("Start Button");
});
```

And remove the period

```
$("#briefing_text").html(callback);
```

Then you'll end up with something more like :

```
function briefingScreen(gameObjectElement) {
    var briefing = $('<div />', {id:'briefing'}),
        start    = $('<div />', {id:'start_button'}),
        text     = $('<div />', {id:'briefing_text'});

    briefing.append(start, text);
    $(gameObjectElement).html(briefing);

    $.post("php/text.php", "teste", function(callback) {
        text.html(callback);
    }, "html");

    start.click(function() {
        alert("Start Button");
    });
}
```